# Archive Listings Filtered by Date Values in a Custom Field/Post Meta?

Tags: customization, archives, wp-query, pre-get-posts

*(**Moderator's Note:** The original title was "using archive by date with a custom date")*

I'm adding an additional date to posts as a custom field. Now I want the archive to show posts by the custom date and not by the published date. For example
I've got a post published today *(22nd December)* but the custom date is set to *1st January*. When I load the URL `archives/date/2011/01` in the browser the posts with the custom date that match are not displayed *(obviously).*

Is there a way to modify the behavior of page generated for the `archives/date/2011/01` URL in order to retrive the posts by the custom date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with many things in WordPress there are several ways to do what you want. I'm going to explain one of them.

[image]

### Remove the `'year'`, `'monthnum'` and `'day'` Query Variables

You can modify the parameters to the query WordPress uses on the archive URLs inside the `'pre_get_posts'` hook. Those parameters are captured as an associative array by the rewrite rules into the property of the `WP_Query` object called `query_vars` variables `'year'`, `'monthnum'` and `'day'`.

When `$wp_query->query_vars` has values for `'year'`, `'monthnum'` and `'day'` WordPress will use them when querying the list of posts so **the first step is to remove those key-value pairs from the query array** using PHP's `unset()` function *(note that `$wp_query` is a global variable in WordPress that contains the current query object as an instance of the `WP_Query` class.)*

The `yoursite_pre_get_posts()` function below triggered by the `'pre_get_posts'` hook will remove those variables from the `query_vars` array but only when the query is the main query *(i.e. the `$query` passed to the hook is exactly equal to the global `$wp_the_query` or `$query===$wp_the_query`) and only when the query is an *archive* query. If you add this to your theme's `functions.php` file you'll find your archive pages display all posts, not just the ones for the date *(so we are halfway to what you want...)*:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'yoursite_pre_get_posts' );
function yoursite_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  global $wp_the_query;
  if ($query===$wp_the_query && $query->is_archive) {
    unset($query->query_vars['year']);
    unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
    unset($query->query_vars['day']);
  }
}
```

### Add Query Variables for Your Custom Field

Now is where it gets a little tricky. In v3.0.x WordPress only allows you to query for custom field using the values in the `query_var` array and it doesn't allow us to apply functions to those criteria either.

The following modification to `yoursite_pre_get_posts()` would allow your archive query to match an exact date assuming you stored the date in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format in the custom field:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'yoursite_pre_get_posts' );
function yoursite_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  global $wp_the_query;
  if ($query===$wp_the_query && $query->is_archive) {
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;
    $date = mktime(0,0,0,$qv['monthnum'],$qv['day'],$qv['year']);
    $qv['meta_key'] = 'Custom Date';
    $qv['meta_value'] = date("Y-m-d",$date);
    unset($qv['year']);
    unset($qv['monthnum']);
    unset($qv['day']);
  }
}
```

And here's what that looks like in a screenshot:

[image]

Of course that's not really want you want. You want to query for year & month instead of just the specific day, or even for just the year. As I said before, that's where it gets tricky.

### Use the `'posts_where'` Hook to Modify the SQL `WHERE` Clause

Basically you need to go deeper into hooks and and call the `'posts_where'` hook, which I always try to avoid if possible since when you are doing text find and replace on SQL query fragments it's very easy to write code that will be incompatible with another plugin that modifies the same SQL query. Nonetheless, if you need it and nothing else will work then it's there for you as a last resort.

So the `yoursite_posts_where()` function searches the `WHERE` clause that WordPress builds for the text `"AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '2011-01'"` and replaces it with the text `"AND SUBSTRING(wp_postmeta.meta_value,1,7) = '2011-01'"`, and here's the code:

```
add_action('posts_where','yoursite_posts_where',10,2);
function yoursite_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
  global $wp_the_query;
  if ($query===$wp_the_query && $query->is_archive) {
    $meta_value = $query->query_vars['meta_value'];
    $length = strlen($meta_value);
    $find = "AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '{$meta_value}'";
    $replace = "AND SUBSTR(wp_postmeta.meta_value,1,{$length}) = '{$meta_value}'";
    $where = str_replace($find,$replace,$where);
  }
  return $where;
}
```

#### Modify `yoursite_pre_get_posts()` to support multiple Year-Month-Day Options

Of course that will require we modify our `yoursite_pre_get_posts()` function to support different length meta values: `'YYYY'`, `'YYYY-MM'` and `'YYYY-MM-DD'` *(Note the use of what appears to be complex use of PHP's `mktime()` and `date()` functions are merely to avoid having to worry about these patterns: `'YYYY-M'`, `'YYYY-MM-D'` and `'YYYY-M-D'`):*

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','yoursite_pre_get_posts' );
function yoursite_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  global $wp_the_query;
  if ($query===$wp_the_query && $query->is_archive) {
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;  // Make it less tedious to reference
    if ($qv['monthnum']==0) // Just search on YYYY
      $date = $qv['year'];
    else if ($qv['day']==0) // Search on YYYY-MM
      $date = date('Y-m',mktime(0,0,0,$qv['monthnum'],1,$qv['year']));
    else
      $date = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$qv['monthnum'],$qv['day'],$qv['year']));
    $qv['meta_key'] = 'Custom Date';
    $qv['meta_value'] = $date;
    unset($qv['year']);
    unset($qv['monthnum']);
    unset($qv['day']);
  }
}
```

And that gives us the following which pretty much wraps up what you were looking for:

[image]

### Code to Display the Custom Date in the Theme

BTW, here's the code I used in the theme to grab the Custom Date meta value:

```
<?php if ($custom_date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Custom Date',true)): ?>
  <h2>Custom Date: <?php echo $custom_date; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### P.S. Remember the User Must Enter in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format

Remember the user needs to enter the Custom Date in the `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format for this to work. Of course you can make it friendlier to the user via several different methods, i.e. in the SQL code or via a `'save_post'` hook that reformats the date but I'll leave that as an exercise for someone else.

#### P.P.S. Option: Save Multiple Meta Values Instead

Another approach would have been to use the `'save_post'` hook to save three (3) hidden meta values in the right format for matching to `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, `'YYYY-MM'` and `'YYYY'` maybe with the meta keys `'_custom_date'`, `'_custom_date_year_month'` `'_custom_date_year'` which would be more resilient to other plugins that might also want to modify the SQL `WHERE` clause but would add three (3) additional hidden custom fields for every post so that might not be a good idea for a blog with a large number of posts and it is possible they could get out of sync somehow.

Comment: i will check your solution and i'll come back later on. It is very well explained thanks

Comment: I made it! user inputs date with jquery tool's dateinput the i've used the last method you explained: i've stored an extra custom field with YYYY-MM formatted date. Then uset default query params and set mine. Thank you very very much i've learnt a lot from your answer!

Comment: @Dalen - Awesome, glad I could help and thanks for the selection and up votes.

Comment: Hi @MikeSchinkel thanks for this post it's really usefull. I've been trying to achieve the same thing but to only effect the archive of a particular custom post type. 

I have an 'events' section in WP and effectively want to short the archive by event date rather than published date but keep the normal archive intact for news?

Comment: Hi @tbwcf to do that you would change `if ($query===$wp_the_query && $query->is_archive)` to `if ($query===$wp_the_query && is_post_type_archive('name_of_event_post_type'))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'll need to either use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) or write a custom query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- copy your `archive.php` (`index.php` if you don't have archive) template to `date.php`
- in `date.php` template use `query_posts()` to override sort, you will need to use

  - [orderby parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters)
  - [preserve original query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_the_Original_Query_.28Pagination_etc..29)

PS hm, I think date archives are usually like `/year/month/`, what are you using to get `/archives/date/year/month/` ?..

PPS actually after looking at Mike's answer this is likely not enough to affect selection of posts. Scratch this.