# How to filter custom post type archive by meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, url-rewriting, custom-post-type-archives, rewrite-tag

I have a problem where I'm trying to build a calendar plugin for a client. I'm having trouble getting a date based archive for the custom post type I'm using. I'm not too well versed in how the wordpress system for handling permalinks is set up on a low level, and I've hit a wall.

**Background:**

The plugin registers a custom post type, `event`. Each event has a meta value field called `kultkal_date`, holds a date in the form of `2011-09-28`. (Events are limited in the sense that each event's date is unique as well, by validation on the `save_post` action).

I've defined a custom permalink for the post type as `/kalendarie/%kultkal_year%/%kultkal_month%/%kultkal_day%`, so the finished URL might look like `/kalendarie/2011/09/28/my-slug`. I've added rewrite tags for the custom permalink using the `init` action like so:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%kultkal_year%','([0-9]{4})');
add_rewrite_tag('%kultkal_month%','([0-9]{2})');
add_rewrite_tag('%kultkal_day%','([0-9]{2})');
```

I have a function to fix the permalink that runs on the `post_type_link` filter:

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post){
    if ($post->post_type != 'event')
        return $link;

    if ($date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'kultkal_date', true)) {
        $dates = explode('-', $date);
        $year = $dates[0];
        $month = $dates[1];
        $day = $dates[2];
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
    $link = str_replace('%kultkal_year%', $year, $link);
    $link = str_replace('%kultkal_month%', $month, $link);
    $link = str_replace('%kultkal_day%', $day, $link);
    return $link;
}
```

Viewing individual posts works. So does the archive page (located at the `/kalendarium/` URL: `has_archive` is set to `kalendarium` when I register the post type).

The trouble starts when I want to filter the posts by year - for instance, `/kalendarium/2011/` or `/kalendarium/2011/09/28/` etc. I've found an answer on how to filter based on meta value for date on built-in posts here: [Archive Listings Filtered by Date Values in a Custom Field/Post Meta?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/archive-listings-filtered-by-date-values-in-a-custom-field-post-meta) - but it doesn't seem to work on custom post types. As soon as I add /year/month/day-parameters to test it, I get the archives for the built-in post type, not even a 404. (So far, I've only tried the first version in the answer above, with all the parameters (year/month/date), not the one with all the combinations + hook for `posts_where` etc.

Here's what the (broken) function I run on `pre_get_posts` looks like:

```
function event_pre_get_posts($query) {
    global $wp_the_query;
    if ($query === $wp_the_query && $query->is_archive()) {
        $qv = &$query->query_vars;
        if (isset($qv['kultkal_year']) && isset($qv['kultkal_month']) && isset($qv['kultkal_day'])) {
            $date = mktime(0,0,0,$qv['kultkal_month'],$qv['kultkal_day'],$qv['kultkal_year']);
            $qv['meta_key'] = 'kultkal_date';
            $qv['meta_value'] = date("Y-m-d", $date);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the solution I'm looking for?

Comment: you need to register your query_vars and also create their rewrite rules.

Comment: @Bainternet Thanks, mate. I thought the purpose of `add_rewrite_tag()` was just that, but I guess I'll have to dig deeper, still highly confused as to how the rewrite stuff works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like Bainternet said in comments, you'll need to mess with `add_query_var` as well as `add_rewrite_rule`.

We usually do something similar to:

```
global $wp;
$wp->add_query_var( 'some_var' );
add_rewrite_rule( 'some/path/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?some_var=$matches[1]' );
```

See this [Wordpress Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16840), as well as documentation on `add_query_var` and [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)